# rotate rectangle with mouse scroll kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

How to rotate rectangle with mouse scroll using kineticjs?
Below link shows rotating a shape with jquery on mousedown. But I want to use mousewheel event and not mousePos since my rectangles are draggable.
http://www.lonhosford.com/content/html5/canvas/rotate_to_mouse.html

Comment: I set up a jsFiddle for anyone interested: http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/FXb6P/

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: +1 for a nice demo of shape auto-rotating to mouse position.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want to rotate the rectangles using KineticJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KineticJS does not natively track mousewheel events.

You can use jQuery + a mousewheel plug-in to receive mousewheel events.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.3/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
```

*Why jQuery?*

You could track mousewheel events without jQuery+plugin, but mousewheel events are not yet standardized across browsers and so a cross-browser non-jQuery solution would be complicated.

Here’s how to listen for mousewheel events on the stage’s container and rotate a Rect:

```
// set this variable to refer to the KineticJS rect you want to rotate

var theRectToRotate    

// set this variable to the number of degrees to rotate when the user mousewheels

var degreeRotationPerMousewheelDelta=5;

// Use jQuery to listen for mousewheel events
// Then rotate the specified rect by the specified degree

$("#container").mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
   theRectToRotate.rotateDeg(delta* degreeRotationPerMousewheelDelta );
   layer.draw();
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/kXJ5q/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.3/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    $("#container").mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
       console.log(delta+": "+deltaX+"/"+deltaY); 
       rect.rotateDeg(delta*5);
       layer.draw();
       event.preventDefault();
    });

    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        width: 100,
        height: 70,
        offset:[50,35],
        fill: 'skyblue',
        stroke: 'lightgray',
        strokeWidth: 3
    });
    layer.add(rect);


    layer.draw();


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Use mousewheel to rotate the rect</h3>
    <h5>This requires a plugin:</h5> 
    <h5>https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel </h5>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: markE: Thanks for above answer. Your code is working but can you please provide me with a solution using KineticJS for IE9 and IE10?

Comment: yup it does but I will prefer to use KinetcJS

Comment: And I am concerned only about IE. Chrome support would be a bonus, but support for other browsers doesn't matter.

Comment: My example fiddle works correctly in IE9+ and it uses the KineticJS library to draw shapes in html canvas.

Comment: yup it does but is it possible to rotate with mousescroll using pure Kineticjs ie. w/o jquery or any other javascript library?

Comment: Possible, of course...Here is a link to the IE onmousewheel event you will need to catch mousewheel events without jquery:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974352(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a means of knowing which rectangle is currently focused/selected (or you want them all to rotate at the same time). The easiest way is to not have it continuous i.e., rotate by a set amount for each mousewheel event.

To do that, you'll need to get the event's wheelDelta, check whether it is positive or negative, and rotate by a set angle your rectangle like so `rect.setRotation(mySetAngleInRadians * isNegativeAngle)`, then redraw the layer.

If you want continuous scrolling, then you'll need to [handle the cases where it isn't supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mousewheel) and decide on a value of scroll distance that corresponds to 360 degrees (full circle), then do something like:

```
rect.setRotation(ev.wheelDelta/fullScrollDistance * 2 * Math.PI)
```

Comment: hey qterton, can you please explain the terms. Particularly, fullScrollDistance. Should it be high or low, I want to rotate the rectangles around their center. And yes, I know how to select a rectangle.